# Канонизация XML на JavaScript

Tags: xml, javascript, canonicalization

Здравствуйте!
Встречался ли кому-нибудь реализованный на JavaScript метод канонизации (canonicalization) XML?
Я имею введу [http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#](http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n)

Comment: Вы собираетесь открыть по одному вопросу на каждый язык?

Comment: Нет, основной вопрос у меня по JS. На C# мне нужно хотелось узнать как сделать канонизацию для проверки, да и по сколько signedXml выдает xml проходящею проверку, а на JS пока сделать такого не получилось, то и как основу. Но я с xml на C# не особо плотно работал и просто не знаю как это сделать, а нужно срочно. Потому и создал ещё один вопрос.  
Только и всего.

Comment: Прошел год, но вот https://github.com/deoxxa/xml-c14n может кто искать будет. Если нужно, то портировать под браузер не сложно.

Comment: пусть мне теперь хоть кто-то скажет, что я ленту захламляю lol