# Каноникализация (канонизация) XML

Tags: xml, canonicalization

Здравствуйте!
Помогите пожалуйста к канонизацией XML (http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n# - Каноникализация XML) примерно такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ws="http://ws.unisoft/" xmlns:rev="http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315" xmlns:rq1="http://ws.unisoft/CPSubPercent/Rq1" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:actor="http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/actors/smev">
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:KeyInfo>
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:Reference URI="#SenderCertificate" />
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="SenderCertificate" />
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="body">
    <ws:async_getId_SendRequest_Tyrim_Pyrim>
      <rev:Message>
        <rev:Sender>
          <rev:Code>CODE63544</rev:Code>
          <rev:Name>ТутИмя</rev:Name>
        </rev:Sender>
        <rev:Recipient>
          <rev:Code>CODE2</rev:Code>
          <rev:Name>Тест</rev:Name>
        </rev:Recipient>
        <rev:Originator>
          <rev:Code>CODE3</rev:Code>
          <rev:Name>Тест</rev:Name>
        </rev:Originator>
        <rev:ServiceName>ТестВебСервис</rev:ServiceName>
        <rev:TypeCode>GSRV</rev:TypeCode>
        <rev:Status>REQUEST</rev:Status>
        <rev:Date>2012-03-13T12:12:12Z</rev:Date>
        <rev:ExchangeType>1</rev:ExchangeType>
        <rev:RequestIdRef />
        <rev:OriginRequestIdRef />
        <rev:ServiceCode />
        <rev:CaseNumber />
        <rev:TestMsg />
      </rev:Message>
      <rev:MessageData>
        <rev:AppData>
          <rq1:Документ ВерсияФормата="1.0" UIDЗапроса="4832bdef-bef7-459a-8397-dc28793f59d4">
            <РегНомер>1</РегНомер>
          </rq1:Документ>
        </rev:AppData>
        <rev:AppDocument>
          <rev:RequestCode>req_4832bdef-bef7-459a-8397-dc28793f59d4</rev:RequestCode>
          <rev:BinaryData>UEsDBBQAAAAIABm=</rev:BinaryData>
        </rev:AppDocument>
      </rev:MessageData>
    </ws:async_getId_SendRequest_Tyrim_Pyrim>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

То есть, это XML SOAP-запроса.
Проблема собственно в том, что я не знаю как привести XML к каноническому виду (каноникализировать) и следовательно да же вручную не могу сделать этого, а мне это нужно запрограммировать (хотя бы, если не каноникализицию произвольной XML, то хотя бы формирование XML уже в каноникализированном виде).

Я конечно читал рекомендации (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n), но не особо понял что же мне то сделать надо с XML...
Пожалуй, единственное что понятно, так это то что в тегах не должно быть лишних пробелов, теги "<тэг />" нужно превратить в "<тэг>".
Но этого явно мало.

*Прошу помощи тех кто с этим уже сталкивался...*

**PS** Отвечая на вопрос "Зачем это нужно" - в идеале для [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/208898/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-xml-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript), но сойдет и простое понимание того какой вид XML должна быть в итоге...

Comment: Сомневаюсь насчет неанглийских тегов и атрибутов коих полно в вашем тексте:

 `<rq1:Документ ВерсияФормата="1.0" UIDЗапроса="4832bdef-bef7-459a-8397-dc28793f59d4"> 
            <РегНомер>1</РегНомер> 
          </rq1:Документ>`

Comment: Это тэги для 1С, так должно быть...

Comment: **klopp** В таком случае я не совснм понимаю, почему не использовать C# изначально. Раз уж всё равно используются какие-то внешние утилиты. Или нужно под unix?  

Вообще нужно что бы работало в браузере, но для начало нужно повторить то что получается на C# вручную, или с какой-то автоматизацией. Отсюда и вопрос.

Comment: А исходников C# класса не найти?

Comment: Как вы себе представляете поиск в нативном коде ?  
Базовые классы представлены DLL.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, MS открывали исходники .NET. Но могу и ошибаться.

Comment: Посмотрю, но сомневаюсь... от мелкомягких дождешься...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file('1.xml');
print $doc->toStringC14N();
```

Comment: Выдал ошибку:

    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
    (c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.

    c:\Perl>canonicalization.pl
    Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
    C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib.) at C:\Perl\canonicalization.pl line 4.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Perl\canonicalization.pl line 4.
    
    c:\Perl>

Comment: КО намекает, что модуль нужно установить. Например, так, если это ActiveState:

`ppm install XML::LibXML`

Comment: Спасибо, я понял что чего-то не хватает, но не знал как это решить...  
Работать с perl после универа ещё не приходилось.  

Кстати, это точно канонизация по [c14n][1]


  [1]: http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#

Comment: Есть ещё метод toStringEC14N(), вот что про него пишут:

>The function is similar to toStringC14N() but follows the 
>XML-EXC-C14N Specification (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n) >for exclusive canonization of XML.

Тут подробней, можно с аргументами поковыряться:

http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0014/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod

Comment: Это ближе к тому что интуитивно я ожидал, но тем не менее для алгоритма расчета кэша результат все равно не тот...  
Кэш не совпадает...  
Буду курить дальше эту тему, спасибо.

Comment: Так если есть с чем сравнить желаемый результат, может от него и плясать? Во всяком случае обработка namespace там есть, как раз по стандарту.

Comment: В том то и дело что результата у меня нет...  
Это XML SOAP-запроса, а заголовке которого вставляется подпись, кэш и сертификат. После подписывания через C# XML записывается в строку, при этом к исходным данным добавляются несколько блоков в header и все...  
Проблема в том что если я беру эту XML и пытаюсь теми же алгоритмами вычислить хотя бы кэш, то у меня он не совпадает с тем что записан в соответствующем тэге. По алгоритму XML должна быть канонизирована перед подписыванием. И вот подписанная на C# проверяется корректно, а JS нет. Потому у меня и подозрение что я канонизирую не правильно

Comment: В таком случае я не совснм понимаю, почему не использовать C# изначально. Раз уж всё равно используются какие-то внешние утилиты. Или нужно под unix?